# Bugs with extracting text between two strings AppleScript method

Tags: applescript

Newbie to AppleScript here, I've learned the following method from other online sources that allows me to extract a string that is between two strings I can define, see code:

```
to ExText(searchText, startText, endText)
    set spaceholder to "x"
    set searchText to ("x" & searchText)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to spaceholder
    set endItems to text item -1 of searchText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText
    set beginningToEnd to text item 1 of endItems
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText
    set finalText to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEnd) as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return finalText
end ExText
```

I'm using this method to extract user's first and last name from an html string obtained by running Javascript id search. I'll do

```
Set SourceString to "<span>firstname lastname</span>"
ExText(SourceString, "<span>", "</span>")
```

It works 90% of the time, but in a few instances, depending on the user's name, it'll get an error with this message

> Can’t make text items 2 thru -1 of "(part of the name)" into type text.

Here are some sample names that'll break this method

```
<span>Xu Chang</span>
<span>Maxim Smith</span>
```

In further testing, I confirmed that any names containing the letter "X" would fail this method. I've examined the actual source strings side by side with the names that contain X and the ones that don't, so it's not the source string but the method itself.

It's worth noting that this error is reproducible everytime.

A rather bizarre behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: AppleScript is not really suited to parsing HTML and really shouldn't be used for it! Looking at the HTML you provided in your other question you should use JavaScript to retrieve the information you were looking for and not parse HTML using AppleScript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the variable of `spaceholder` from "x" to "xx" should work

```
to ExText(searchText, startText, endText)
    set spaceholder to "xx"
    set searchText to ("xx" & searchText)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to spaceholder
    set endItems to text item -1 of searchText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText
    set beginningToEnd to text item 1 of endItems
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText
    set finalText to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEnd) as text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return finalText
end ExText
```

Comment: wch1zpink for the rescue again! Yes I had that figured out a few hours ago and changed it to "~" some thing that'll never (or should never) happen in a name. but... DUH "xx" or "xxx" would've done just fine and probably better LOL thank you kind sir once again. PS. I wonder why the 2 first lines are needed.

Comment: @DrewCanaima Here is some (what I think is) good advice.  Since you are admittedly an AppleScript "noob", one of the best learning methods is trial and error.  Since you are curious what the importance of the first two lines are... Try altering or omitting them one at a time and re run the code and evaluate any error messages.  A huge percentage of Final versions of my code usually involve the process of "hmmm... That did not work let me try this.. This did not work let me try that and this, etc..."

Comment: thank you for the advice!! I'm glad I'm on the right track because I have done just that! Although I wasted a few hours to figure out nothing (lol, because the result itself doesn't really explain what took place) but I did for other methods I grabbed from the internet and have learned from doing just that! Glad to hear that's what experts do as well!